# when should I add "it" after believe or understand?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Is there any difference?

> I really can't understand it.
>
> **and**
>
> I really can't understand.

Also

> I couldn't believe.
>
> **and**
>
> I couldn't believe it

Comment: 'It' refers to the information or statement that you can't believe or understand. If you state what that is - "I couldn't believe I had succeeded at last" - you don't need 'it' in the sentence.

Comment: If you don't have an object after "understand", you're making a general statement rather than a statement about a specific thing.

Comment: It's like the difference between "I can't eat" and "I can't eat meat"

Answer (score 1):

Like any other context, we use the pronoun "it" to refer to a *specific thing* previously mentioned or easily identified.

Let's say that you ask somebody to explain *algebra* to you, because you don't understand algebra. If, after they had explained you said "I don't understand it", as the subject you are speaking about is algebra, it would be taken that "it" refers to this and that you still don't understand algebra.

However, if you simply said "I don't understand" this could mean that you didn't understand the way it was explained to you, or that you don't understand something new which has been brought up during the explanation. Maybe the person replied in a language you didn't understand!

It isn't particularly idiomatic to say "I don't believe" without directing this at something - "I don't believe *it*" or "I don't believe *you*".

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps a lot!

Comment: The intransitive (some would say covert transitive) "I don't believe" is sometimes heard as an alternative to "I'm not a believer", with the implication that the 'it' is in God or a particular Faith. Perhaps more often heard jocularly, when someone is trying to force a pet 'doctrine' (say 'steam locomotives are best in every way') on a victim. But, as you imply, rare without inviting context.